# Licensing issue for RSA and Rijndael algorithms

Tags: licensing, software-patent, encryption, commercial

I'm using .Net to build a commercial application, i.e. a secure chat application. This application is using RSA and Rijndael algorithms.

Do we need licenses for using RSA and Rijndael algorithms for commercial product?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you don't need any licenses for neither of them.

Patents for RSA have expired on September 21, 2000. Even before that, it was also [released as public domain](http://www.rsa.com/press_release.aspx?id=261).

Rijndael was submitted to NIST as Federal Information Processing Standard for AES, and is officially [declared by authors to be patent free](http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/rijndael/rijndael-ip.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

For RSA algorithm, no license required for any products developed after [September 6, 2000](http://www.rsa.com/press_release.aspx?id=261). The date is important.

> BEDFORD, MA.— RSA® Security Inc. (NASDAQ: RSAS) today announced it has
>   released the RSA public key encryption algorithm into the public
>   domain, allowing anyone to create products that incorporate their own
>   implementation of the algorithm. This means that RSA Security has
>   waived its rights to enforce the patent for any development activities
>   that include the RSA algorithm occurring after September 6, 2000.